# Table access query

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb6

In our server client software in vb6 with SQL2005, On server side one SQL table is continuously updated by data and we need to display data from this same table on client at running time. Pleases help how to access this same table from server and client so that data is continuously updated from server side and records in this table show on client software without error.

Answer (score 2):

Your VB application needs to poll the table on occasion (as often as you need it to) to gather the new data, then display it as needed. Further assistance is going to require more information from you (such as, are you just asking us to write this for you?).

Answer (score 0):

In VB6 you can use a timer control on the form to periodically check and reload the data to the form.  If you are using an ADO recordset then reload the recordset with the table data and rebind to your form's values OR if you are using the built-in binding you will have to tell the form to reload and/or rebind.  It's been a while since I have done VB6 so my memory on the exact steps is a little rusty.